# Struggling with aligning buttons using CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to line up the two buttons data analysis and graphing and automated analysis pipeline for bioreactor.

for full code please see here: https://github.com/Betaglutamate/online-cv/blob/master/_includes/skills.html

```css
/*   
 * Template Name: Orbit - Responsive Resume/CV Template for Developers
 * Version: 1.0
 * Author: Xiaoying Riley
 * Twitter: @3rdwave_themes
 * License: Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 License
 * Website: http://themes.3rdwavemedia.com/
*/


/* styles.css */


/* ======= Base ======= */

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: #545E6C;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 30px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-weight: 700;
}

a {
  color: #2d7788;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #1a454f;
}

a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}

p {
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.wrapper {
  background: #42A8C0;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.sidebar-wrapper {
  background: #42A8C0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 240px;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 800px;
  color: #fff;
}

.contact-info {
  font-size: 13px;
}

.container {
  display: inline;
  /* or inline-flex */
  padding: 0em;
}

.sidebar-wrapper a {
  color: #fff;
}

.sidebar-wrapper .profile-container {
  padding: 30px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}

.sidebar-wrapper .name {
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 900;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.sidebar-wrapper .tagline {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.sidebar-wrapper .profile {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.sidebar-wrapper .contact-list .fa {
  margin-right: 5px;
  font-size: 18px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.sidebar-wrapper .contact-list li {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.sidebar-wrapper .contact-list li:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.sidebar-wrapper .contact-list .email .fa {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.sidebar-wrapper .container-block {
  padding: 30px;
}

.sidebar-wrapper .container-block-title {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.sidebar-wrapper .degree {
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.sidebar-wrapper .education-container .item {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.sidebar-wrapper .education-container .item:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.sidebar-wrapper .education-container .meta {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.sidebar-wrapper .education-container .time {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.sidebar-wrapper .languages-container .lang-desc {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}

.sidebar-wrapper .languages-list {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.sidebar-wrapper .languages-list li {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.sidebar-wrapper .languages-list li:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.sidebar-wrapper .interests-list {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.sidebar-wrapper .interests-list li {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.sidebar-wrapper .interests-list li:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.main-wrapper {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 60px;
  padding-right: 300px;
}

.main-wrapper .section-title {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #2d7788;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.main-wrapper .section-title .fa {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -ms-border-radius: 50%;
  -o-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-background-clip: padding;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  background: #2d7788;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 8px;
  font-size: 16px;
  position: relative;
  top: -2px;
}

.main-wrapper .section {
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.main-wrapper .experiences-section .item {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.main-wrapper .upper-row {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.main-wrapper .job-title {
  color: #3F4650;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.main-wrapper .time {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  color: #97AAC3;
}

.main-wrapper .company {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #97AAC3;
}

.main-wrapper .project-title {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.main-wrapper .projects-section .intro {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.main-wrapper .projects-section .item {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.skillset .item {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.skillset .level-title {
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.level-title {
  display: inline-block
}

.skillset .level-bar {
  height: 12px;
  background: #f5f5f5;
}

.skillset .level-bar-inner {
  height: 12px;
  background: #7bc2d3;
}

.footer {
  padding: 30px;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.footer .copyright {
  line-height: 1.6;
  color: #545E6C;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.footer .fa-heart {
  color: #fb866a;
}


/* Extra small devices (phones, less than 768px) */

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .sidebar-wrapper {
    position: static;
    width: inherit;
  }
  .main-wrapper {
    padding: 30px;
  }
  .main-wrapper .time {
    position: static;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 5px;
  }
  .main-wrapper .upper-row {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}


/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */


/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .skillset .level-title {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  .skillset .level-bar {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 70%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
  }
}


/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */


/* Ex-Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */


/* 
used for profile image
*/

.profile-img {
  max-width: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border: 0px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

````html
<div class="item">
  <h3 class="level-title">Python</h3>
  <!-- modal start here -->
  <div class="container">
    <div id="python-modal-profile" class="modal fade" aria-labelledby="my-modalLabel" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog" data-dismiss="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Automated Analysis Pipeline for Bioreactor</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <img src="/online-cv/assets/images/Bioreactor.svg" class="img-responsive" style="width: 100%;">
            <div class="details">
              <p class="mt-3"><strong>Building an automated analysis software for our custom built bioreactor</strong> </p>
              <p>
                Generating growth curves for bacteria manually is a time-consuming and tedious activity performed by laboratories across the world. Using bioreactors can automate this process. However, these are very expensive putting this technology out of reach for
                many smaller laboratories. Our lab designed a modular bioreactor to make this technology affordable for everyone. I designed an <a href="https://github.com/Betaglutamate/Bioreactor" target="_blank">analysis program that</a>                takes raw text files output by the bioreactor and automatically calculates and graphs the growth rates.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <a href="/online-cv/assets/documents/Plotly_example.html" target="_blank" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" role="button" aria-disabled="true">data analysis and graphing</a>
    <button id="show-img" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm project" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#python-modal-profile">Automated analysis pipeline for Bioreactor</button>
  </div>
  <!-- //modal button ends here -->
  where does this go
</div>
what about this
<!-- //Modal item -->


```
````

[image: problem picture]

Comment: For a question regarding CSS it would be helpful to post the CSS code as well

Comment: Hi, I included the CSS code. I am very inexperienced with this. Please look at the site here: https://betaglutamate.github.io/online-cv/

I want to line up the two buttons but do not understand how to. Thank you

Comment: No worries. Line them up like the two button above those? If so, you did, but the second button's text is too long. That's why it falls into a new line. If you shorten the button text, both buttons are side by side

Comment: If you cannot shorten the button text, duplicate the "Python" `.item`, give it an empty title (`&nbsp;`), and place one button in the first `.item`, and the second button in the new one, so they're both aligned left right below each other

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've included a very basic example in JSFiddle, since your example has so much code. ;) Next time I would advice a small sample, this way it is easier for us to debug your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

**Example**

If you want to get 2 buttons next to each other you can use flexbox for this, so it will also have a better responsive behaviour: https://jsfiddle.net/8tgm5yo6/

**Example HTML**

```
<div class="example">
  <h3 class="example_title">I am some title</h3>
  <div class="example_buttons">
  <button class="example_button" type="button">I am a button</button>
  <button class="example_button" type="button">I am a button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Example CSS**

```
.example {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}

.example_title {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}

.example_buttons {
  margin: 0 0 0 auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;

  display: inline-flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
}

.example_button {
  margin: 0.4em 0.2em;
}
```

As also other point out there is also not enough space to align the buttons next to each other. 
You could shorten your button content or increase the container size a little bit, but add a little extra margin because browsers do not render HTML & CSS exactly the same, it can be different by a few pixels.

**Increase container width**

You can set your container width to 1070 to make the buttons fit:

```
.wrapper {
    max-width: 1070px;
}
```

Of course this problem will still persist on smaller screens (tablets/phones) or resized browsers.